# Inspect Canvas Background

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Looking at a `CANVAS` and it seems to have a background image. However I can't for the life of me see where it is set. Is there anyway I can inspect the canvas or set the background through the Chrome console?

I've tried the following with no avail

```
var images = document.querySelectorAll("canvas");

    for(var i = 0;i < images.length;i++){
console.log(images[i]);
      images[i].style.background = 'none';
    }
```

Comment: If the image has been rendered to the canvas (and is not the canvas.style.background) you can not find out what the image is unless you find the render calls that put the image there. The canvas only comprehends pixels, it does not store any other details in regard to what is rendered.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to target it with:

`var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
console.log(context.fillStyle);`

And change it with:

`context.fillStyle = none;`

Hope this works! :)

Comment: What if it was written with drawImage?